# Laravel 7 419 Page Expired error after refresh login's laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using auth system, and after user logged in if I refresh the page I get the 419 page expired error. I overrided authenticated method to redirect to profile after login. Here's my controller:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

protected function authenticated()
{
    return view("user.profile");
}
```

And here's my User model:

```
    /**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];
const UPDATED_AT = null;

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Comment: Make sure the `SESSION_DRIVER` variable is NOT null in your .env

Comment: @TalhaF. It's not null. It's like SESSION_DRIVER = file;

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the render function in app\Exceptions\Handler.php by adding the code below.

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
    return redirect('/login');
}
```